# Javascript audio loop for 3 times

Tags: javascript, loops, audio

I need to repeat a sound 3 time in my page.  I tried the same by below code. But audio.play() seems to be not waiting for the clip to be completed. Please help on the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }
        async function play() {

            var audio = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3');
            for (let index = 0; index <3; index++) {

                await sleep(1000);
                await console.log(index)
                await audio.play();

            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <button type='button' onclick="play()">Play</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `setTimeout` doesn't need to be wrapped in a promise, you just need to make it so that the next play call is triggered *within* the `setTimeout` callback. I would suggest doing this with a recursive function:

```
function playSound(audio, numberOfTimes = 1, delay = 3000, firstTime = true ){
    if(firstTime){
       audio.play();
    }
    setTimeout( () => {
       if(!firstTime){
           audio.play();
       }
       numberOfTimes--;
       if(numberOfTimes > 0){
         playSound(audio,numberOfTimes,delay, false);
       }
    }, delay)
  }

  function playTRexRoar() {
        var audio = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3');
        playSound(audio,3,3000);
    }

  playTRexRoar();
```

**(Edit: added check for if it is the first time the clip is played, so that it can play immediately rather than waiting for the delay)**

Comment: Hi, I tried the same, but still the ```audio.play();``` is not waiting for the audio clip to complete.  I tried with a longer audio clip, and the recursive function is getting called in between the audio play. Added consol.log to know it.

Comment: This is waiting for the specified delay, not until the clip is finished. It is a working version of what your initial code was trying to do with the sleep() method you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is:

- initially set the Boolean property `loop` to `true`
- deploy a `setTimeout` for three times the `duration` of the sound file
- play the sound file
- at the end of the `setTimeout`, ensure the Boolean property `loop` resets to `false`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const playSound = (audioURL, playCount = 1) => {

  const audioContext = new AudioContext();   
  audioContext.resume();

  const audioClip = new Audio(audioURL);

  /** N.B. This line:
  
      audioClip.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => console.log(audioClip.duration));
  
      tells us that the sound file duration is 2.142 seconds **/

  const audioClipDuration = 2142;
  audioClip.loop = true;
  setTimeout(() => audioClip.loop = false, (audioClipDuration * (playCount - 1)));
  audioClip.play();
}

playSound('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3', 3);
```

---

### Alternative approach to looping:

After adding the approach above two weeks ago, I've discovered that using the `.loop` boolean property doesn't always work reliably if the sound clip is short (ie. one second or less).

An alternative approach (below) builds an array of T-Rex roars and plays each individual roar once only before discarding it.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const playSound = (audioURL, playCount = 1) => {

  const audioContext = new AudioContext();   
  audioContext.resume();

  let playCountArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < playCount; i++) {

    let soundInstance = new Audio(audioURL);
    playCountArray.push(soundInstance);

    if (playCountArray.length < playCount) {

      playCountArray[i].addEventListener('ended', () => {playCountArray.shift(); playCountArray[0].play();});
    }
  }
  
  playCountArray[0].play();
};


playSound('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3', 3);
```