# JavaScript: Play each audio file in a playlist multiple times consecutively, with a pause between plays

Tags: javascript

I have an audio playlist for language learning. Each file of playlist is supposed to be played once or more times consecutively, and so the whole playlist, with a pause between plays. Right now I can play in this mode only a single file, not the whole playlist.

The HTML part:

```
<div id="audio-files">
    <audio preload="auto" class="myAudio">
        <source src="https://example.com/audiofile0001.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    ....
    <audio preload="auto" class="myAudio">
        <source src="https://example.com/audiofile1001.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</div>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
```

The JavaScript part (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60340947/1354580)) that works if playing only one file, not the whole list. The only problem here is the *pauseAudio()* function, that doesn't stop all playbacks.

```
const div = document.querySelectorAll( 'div#audio-files .myAudio' );
var numberOfTimes = 2;
var delay = 3000;

let audioFile = div[0];

function playAudio() { playSound( audioFile, numberOfTimes, delay ); }
function pauseAudio() { audioFile.pause(); } // works not good

function playSound( audioFile, numberOfTimes = 1, delay = 0, firstTime = true ) {
    if( firstTime ) { audioFile.play(); }

    setTimeout( () => {
        if( ! firstTime ) { audioFile.play(); }

        if( numberOfTimes > 0 ) {
            numberOfTimes--;
            playSound( audioFile, numberOfTimes, delay, firstTime = false );
        }

    }, delay );
}
```

I suppose that the *playAudio()* function must changed to get the desired result (playing the entire playlist), but I can't figure out how exactly to do it. This is what I tried:

```
function playAudio() {

    for( let i = 0; i < div.length; i++ ) {

        let audioFile = div[i];

        if( i === 0 ) { playSound( audioFile, numberOfTimes, delay ); }

        let timeInterval = audioFile.duration * 1000 * 2 + delay * 2;

        setTimeout( () => {
            if( i > 0 ) { playSound( audioFile, numberOfTimes, delay ); }
        }, timeInterval );
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const audioElems = document.querySelectorAll('.myAudio');
const desiredPlayCount = 2;
const desiredDelayMs = 2000;

let audioIndex = 0;
let playCount = 0;
let timeoutId = null;

function playAudio() {
  audioElems[audioIndex].play();
}

function pauseAudio() {
  audioElems[audioIndex].pause();
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

audioElems.forEach(audioElem =>
  audioElem.addEventListener('ended', onEnded)
);

function onEnded() {
  playCount++;
  
  if (playCount < desiredPlayCount) {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      audioElems[audioIndex].play();
    }, desiredDelayMs);
  } else {
    playCount = 0;
    audioIndex = (audioIndex + 1) % audioElems.length;
    
    if (audioIndex !== 0) {
      //auto play next audio file in the sequence
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        audioElems[audioIndex].play();
      }, desiredDelayMs);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="audio-files">
  <audio preload="auto" class="myAudio">
    <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/riceracer_assets/music/start.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <audio preload="auto" class="myAudio">
    <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/bonus.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <audio preload="auto" class="myAudio">
    <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/player_shoot.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</div>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
```

Comment: Your code looks good, but this is only for one file in the playlist. How about multiple files?

Comment: Updated my answer to handle multiple files.

Comment: Also made pause button work even if pressed during the delay between plays.

Comment: Great! I tested several times, no error! I also discovered a bonus - if you press the "PlayAudio" button during the pause between playbacks (*desiredDelayMs*), this pause is skipped, I like that! Thank you very much!