# Play an audio playlist multiple times with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have several "audio" sections in a web page. All I want is to play them as a playlist with vanilla JavaScript as follows. After clicking a button, the audio files in these sections will each be played several times, say two more times, with a certain pause between plays, say 1 second, at a certain playback speed , say 1.25x, one after the other, after which the whole list should be played in the same way a few more times, say twice. I wrote the necessary code, see below, which works as I want, but only until the point where the entire playlist needs to be replayed. From that moment, the first audio in the list is played, as desired, but after that, consecutively, the other files also start to be played, without stopping the previous ones, so that, at a given moment, they are played all together at the same time. I marked the section where the playlist repetition starts with a comment in the code. What is wrong there and how can this be fixed? I will appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<button id="lsm-play-list" type="button">Play list</button>

<audio class="audio-element">
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/wei-geet-et-iech.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<!-- other similar sections between -->

<audio class="audio-element">
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/wei-geet-et.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const playButton = document.getElementById('lsm-play-list');
    const audioElements = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-element');

    let playbackSpeed = 1.5;  // default audio playback speed
    let pauseDuration = 1;     // default pause between plays in seconds
    let fileRepeatCount = 2;   // default audio file repeat count
    let listRepeatCount = 2;   // default playlist repeat count
    let currentAudioIndex = 0; // track current audio element
    let repeatCount = fileRepeatCount; // keep track of audio file repeats

    let isPlaylistPlaying = false;

    // event listener for 'Play list' button
    playButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (!isPlaylistPlaying) {
            isPlaylistPlaying = true;
            playButton.textContent = 'Pause list';

            if (currentAudioIndex < audioElements.length - 1) {
                playAudio(currentAudioIndex);
            }
        } else {
            isPlaylistPlaying = false;
            pauseAudio(currentAudioIndex);
            playButton.textContent = 'Continue';
        }
    });

    // play audio elements
    function playAudio(index) {
        const audio = audioElements[index];

        const playCurrentAudio = () => {
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            audio.playbackRate = playbackSpeed;
            audio.play();
        };

        if (isPlaylistPlaying) {
            if (index < audioElements.length - 1) {
                currentAudioIndex = index;
            }

            playCurrentAudio();
        }

        audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            if (isPlaylistPlaying && repeatCount > 1) {
                repeatCount--;

                setTimeout(() => {
                    playCurrentAudio();
                }, pauseDuration * 1000); // pauses in milliseconds

            } else 

            if (isPlaylistPlaying && index < audioElements.length - 1) {
                currentAudioIndex = index + 1;
                repeatCount = fileRepeatCount;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    playAudio(index + 1);
                }, pauseDuration * 1000);
            } else 

            // here starts the playlist problematic replay part
            if (isPlaylistPlaying && currentAudioIndex === audioElements.length - 1) {
                if (listRepeatCount > 1) {
                    listRepeatCount--;
                    currentAudioIndex = 0;
                    repeatCount = fileRepeatCount;

                    // Play the playlist again
                    playAudio(0);
                } else {
                    isPlaylistPlaying = false;
                    playButton.textContent = 'Play list';
                }
            }

        });
    }

    function pauseAudio(index) {
        const audio = audioElements[index];
        audio.pause();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the [answer to an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73792653/1354580) of mine that I had forgotten about, which I already found after I had published this question, I solved the problem. In fact, I gave up the code presented in the question and started from the one in the answer mentioned above, updating it. Obviously, somehow they are similar.

The final code is fully functional and works exactly as I wrote in my question. If there are suggestions for improvement, I will be grateful.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const playButton = document.getElementById('lsm-play-list');
    const audioElems = document.querySelectorAll('.audio-element');

    let playbackSpeed = 1.5; // default audio playback speed
    let desiredFilePlay = 2; // default audio file repeat count
    let desiredListPlay = 2; // default playlist repeat count
    let desiredDelaySec = 1; // default pause between plays in seconds

    let filePlayCount = 0; // audio files playbacks counter
    let listPlayCount = 0; // playlist playbacks counter
    let timeoutId = null;  // ID of active timeout

    let audioIndex = 0; // track current audio element
    let isListPlaying = false; // state of playlist

    // event listener for 'Play list' button
    playButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (!isListPlaying) {
            isListPlaying = true;
            playButton.textContent = 'Pause list';
            playAudioElement();
        } else {
            isListPlaying = false;
            playButton.textContent = 'Continue';
            pauseAudioElement();
        }
    });

    function playAudioElement() {
        audioElems[audioIndex].currentTime = 0;
        audioElems[audioIndex].playbackRate = playbackSpeed;
        audioElems[audioIndex].play();
    }

    function pauseAudioElement() {
        audioElems[audioIndex].pause();
        // clear active timeout to ensure audio pausing
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    audioElems.forEach(audioElem =>
        audioElem.addEventListener('ended', onEnded)
    );

    function onEnded() {
        filePlayCount++;

        if (audioIndex === audioElems.length - 1 && 
            filePlayCount === desiredFilePlay) { // if it was last audio

            listPlayCount++; // count playlist playings

            // if multiple playlist playbacks are set up
            if (listPlayCount < desiredListPlay) {
                audioIndex = 0;
                filePlayCount = 0;
                // play playlist from start
            } else {
                // if no more playlist playbacks, stop
                isListPlaying = false;
                playButton.textContent = 'Play list';
                filePlayCount = 0;
                listPlayCount = 0;
                audioIndex = 0;
                return;
            }
        }

        // if multiple file playbacks are set up
        if (filePlayCount === desiredFilePlay) {
            filePlayCount = 0;
            audioIndex++;
            // play next audio
        }

        setNextPlayback();
    };

    function setNextPlayback() {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { // set a pause
            playAudioElement();        // before next audio
        }, desiredDelaySec * 1000);    // in milliseconds
    }
});
```